# Enumerate SqlDataReader Columns

Tags: c#, .net

Given the following code snip:

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        var count = reader.FieldCount; // the first column must be name all subsequent columns are treated as data
        var data = new List<double>();
        for (var i = 1; i < count; i++)
        {
            data.Add(Convert.ToDouble(reader[i].ToString()));
        }
        barChartSeries.Add(new ColumnBarChart.ColumnChartSeries((string)reader[0],
                                                                data));
        columnChart.xAxis.categories.Add((string)reader[0]);
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way to eliminate the for loop? Perhaps using linq?

reader[0] will always be a string
reader[0+?] will be a double

I want to pull all the doubles into a list if possible.

Comment: Why do you *want* to eliminate the loop here? I would get rid of the double-to-string-to-double conversion (use `GetDouble` instead), but the rest seems okay to me...

Comment: @JonSkeet Good point - I dislike looping is all. This will be pull a HighChart object stored as json, deserializing the object, then querying the database (potentially a different db) based upon the conStr identifier in the object, then parsing the data and then re-serializing to json for returning in a REST service. Speed is somewhat of a concern I suppose.

Comment: You could replace the `for` with `Enumerable.Range` and do it with `Linq`, but basically you are just swapping a `for` with a `foreach` in that case, your code seems fine to me, I can see no benefit of refactoring out the `for` loop

Comment: @Wjdavis5, Jon is right, LINQ won't give you any benefits. Besides using `GetDouble` there's only one thing to do: init your list with `count - 1` as capacity to reduce reallocations, or even use fixed-size array instead. Also, use `GetString` for column 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Speed is somewhat of a concern I suppose.

Then you're focusing on entirely the wrong problem.

Out of the things you're doing here, looping is the *least* inefficient part. More worrying is that you're converting from a `double` to `string` and then back to `double`. At least fix your code to:

```
for (var i = 1; i < count; i++)
{
    data.Add(reader.GetDouble(i));
}
```

You could create the list with the known size, too:

```
List<double> data = new List<double>(count - 1);
```

Even then, I strongly suspect that's going to be irrelevant compared with the serialization and database access.

Whatever you do, *something* is going to be looping. You could go to great lengths to *hide* the looping (e.g. by writing an extension method to iterate over all the values in a row) - but really, I don't see that there's anything wrong with it here.

I strongly advise you to avoid micro-optimizing until you've *proven* there's a problem. I'd be utterly astonished if this bit of code you're worrying about is a bottleneck at all. Generally, you should write the simplest code which achieves what you want it to, decide on your performance criteria and then test against them. Only move away from simple code when you need to.

Comment: thank you. i understand what you are saying. i appreciate the words of wisdom.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can see to remove the `forloop` is to use `Enumerable.Range`.

But anyway you could do something like:

```
   var data = new List<double>(Enumerable.Range(1, count).Select(i => reader.GetDouble(i)));
```

But I see no benefit to this approch, and it just makes the code unreadable

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can loop on it because

```
public class SqlDataReader : DbDataReader, IDataReader, IDisposable, IDataRecord
```

and this class does not implement `IEnumerable`

Comment: `SqlDataReader` extends `DbDataReader`, which implements `IEnumerable`.  It just doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, but you can use `Cast<T>` on it

Comment: I don't have have any thing when jon skeet answer you question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the LINQ Cast method to get something you can use other LINQ methods on, but I agree with the other posters - there's nothing wrong with a for loop.  LINQ methods will just use a less efficient loop in the background.

I believe this should work, but haven't set up a data set to test it.

```
reader.Cast<Double>().Skip(1).ToList();
```